# elasticsearch terms query not fetching all documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

Below is terms query with `_msearch`. But its not giving all result.As of now, it only return result for `4161` even though data exists for `4402` as well.

please suggest solution.

```
GET _msearch
{ "index": ["index1", "index2", "index3"]}
{"query": {"terms": {"user_id": [4161,4402] } }}
```

type of user_id is `long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to increase the `size` parameter or sort the data differently. By default only 10 hits come back from a search query and it might well be the case that the first 10 documents being returned are all for `user_id: 4161`.

```
GET _msearch
{ "index": ["index1", "index2", "index3"]}
{"size": 100, "query": {"terms": {"user_id": [4161,4402] } }}
```

The `terms` query is an OR query, i.e. `terms: [4161,4402]` is equivalent to `term: 4161 OR term: 4402`.

Another way since you're using `_msearch` is to send one query per index, since you'll be returning more data, you might be lucky and get data for both users.

```
GET _msearch
{ "index": "index1"}
{"query": {"terms": {"user_id": [4161,4402] } }}
{ "index": "index2"}
{"query": {"terms": {"user_id": [4161,4402] } }}
{ "index": "index3"}
{"query": {"terms": {"user_id": [4161,4402] } }}
```

Comment: size param work